# return class in template file yii

Tags: php, class, yii, reference

I'm new to Yii, and i am struggling with the display of some classes.
I have a very basic example:

I got my template file: themes/classic/views/layout/main.php and i want to call a class there.

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Categorieën</h2>
        <p>
            <?php
            echo AdminController::producten(); //<--- this does not work!
            ?>
        </p>
    </div><!-- box -->
</div><!-- col-lg-2 -->
```

The class is protected/controllers/AdminController.php

In that class i have a function called producten()

```
public function producten(){
    return 'Hier komen categorieën!';
}
```

I want to view that function (in this case a string) in my template page.

Can you guys show me how, if this is possible ofcourse. Or should i use a widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make below code working:

```
echo AdminController::producten();
```

You need to change your method to static method like below:

```
public static function producten(){
    return 'Hier komen categorieën!';
}
```

On the other hand, if your controller is extended from a base controller which holds your main layout, you can use `$this` keyword to get a method.

When you install a fresh yii web application base controller is under `/protected/components/Controller.php` which all controllers will extend that. So if you put your method in that Controller, it will be accessible via all controller which are extended from base controller.

Comment: This does not work. I'm in a theme file not in the controller page itself. So how do i call another class inside another page?

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl under all conditions, you will use this theme in a controller. You will never user that theme file alone. Also, In each view `$this` refers to controller which rendered view. You can define your method in your base controller and use it under theme main file by `$this->methodName()`

Comment: I see what you mean. If i go to the admincontroller page, it works. But i want it to also work when i'm lets say in the site controller. But that does not work. How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you have a base controller which you defined your main layout? When you install a fresh yii web application it is under `/protected/components/Controller.php` which all controllers will extend that. So if you put your method in that Controller, it is accessible via all controller which are extended from that.

Comment: You rock @Ali! That worked! I put the function inside the controller class, and now i can see it everywhere! Thanks man!

Comment: Can you also help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757267/category-hierarchy-php-mysql-in-yii