# Category Hierarchy (PHP/MySQL) in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, categories, hierarchy

I found this here: [Category Hierarchy (PHP/MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452472/category-hierarchy-php-mysql)

And i want to display that code, but it is not working correctly.

I got the following Hierarchy:

```
-Airsoft
--Scopes
```

That's all. But the code is displaying:

```
-Airsoft
--Scopes (So far so good)
-Scopes <--- this one should not be here!
```

Here's the code:

```
public static function producten(){

        $connection=Yii::app()->db;   // assuming you have configured a "db" connection
        $sql = 'SELECT id, parent, naam FROM categories ORDER BY naam';
        $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
        $dataReader=$command->query();

        $refs = array();

        foreach ($dataReader as $row)
        {
            $ref = & $refs[$row['id']];

            $ref['parent'] = $row['parent'];
            $ref['naam']   = $row['naam'];

            if ($row['parent'] == NULL)
            {
                $list[$row['id']] = & $ref;
            }
            else
            {
                $refs[$row['parent']]['children'][$row['id']] = & $ref;
            }
        }

        function toUL(array $array)
        {
            $html = '<ul>' . PHP_EOL;

            foreach ($array as $value)
            {
                $html .= '<li>' . $value['naam'];
                if (!empty($value['children']))
                {
                    $html .= toUL($value['children']);
                }
                $html .= '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
            }

            $html .= '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;

            return $html;
        }
        print_r($refs);
        echo toUL($refs);
    }
```

The `print_r()` in there is displaying:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [parent] => [naam] => Airsoft [children] => Array ( [2] => Array ( [parent] => 1 [naam] => Scopes ) ) ) [2] => Array ( [parent] => 1 [naam] => Scopes ) )
```

Can somebody figure out what's wrong with the code and help me please?

Comment: Try adding GROUP BY naam

Comment: @Naruto no difference :(

Comment: Well the problem is, that you don't check if child already exists for that parent..

Comment: @Naruto okay.. and you got/know a fix for that?

Comment: Not tested, but something like:

    if(!(in_array($row['parent'], $refs){
         $refs[$row['parent']]['children'][$row['id']] = & $ref;
    }

Comment: @Naruto Still does not work.. Tried it everywhere :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$connection=Yii::app()->db;   // assuming you have configured a "db" connection
$sql = 'SELECT id, parent, naam FROM categories ORDER BY naam';
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
$dataReader=$command->queryAll();


function createList($elements, $parentId = 0) {
        $branch = array();

        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            if ($element['parent'] == $parentId) {
                $children = createList($elements, $element['id']);
                if ($children) {
                    $element['children'] = $children;
                }
                $branch[] = $element;
            }
        }

        return $branch;
    }

    $list = createList($dataReader);
    CVarDumper::dump($list, 5678, true);
```

Comment: Please note that this is given from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587341/recursive-function-to-generate-multidimensional-array-from-database-result/ but matches your problem.